# If key exist into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$modules = array( 
    'module1' => array(
        'position' => 2
    )
);
```

How I can check that `module1` exist and how to get the position number ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$x=$modules['module1']['position'];` ?

Comment: [Literally in the manual under "arrays"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use *array_key_exists()* function

**Code**

```
if (array_key_exists("module1", $modules)) {
    echo $modules["module1"]["position"]
}
else {
    echo "module1 doesn't exist in the array"
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use isset function to get it

```
if(isset($modules['module1']) && isset($modules['module1']['position'])) {
 $value = $modules['module1']['position'];
}
```

Hope this will work

Comment: this code has errors. please test your code before answering

Comment: You could just edit the code or point out what the problem is @nogad . I believe this is the lightest answer in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a value exists in an array, you can use `array_key_exists (value, $ array)`.

To get the value of this array you must use `$array[key][value]`. An example is in the case below, where it checks whether the key exists, if it exists prints the value, if there is no exists then print that was not found:

```
$modules = array(
    'module1' => array(
        'position' => 2
    )
);

$value = 'module1';

if(array_key_exists($value, $modules)) {
  echo $modules[$value]['position'];
} else {
  echo 'not found';
}
```

The variable `$value` may receive the value of you want to fetch. Or you can replace the place where it appears with value you want to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
$module['module1']['position']=2;
foreach($module as $index=>$item){
    foreach($item as $i){
        if($index=='module1'){
            echo $i;
        }   
    }
}
```

Above code help you to determine key value and you can implement your logic arbitrarily

Comment: Use four spaces to make SO read is as code. Br tags and tabs don't work.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help